# How to use the admin autocomplete field in a custom form?

Tags: django

In the Django admin interface you can set a field to be a [autocomplete field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields), e.g.:

```
autocomplete_fields = ('countries', )
```

This works great for admin pages, how does one use the autocomplete field in a custom view/form? My research points towards django-autocomplete-light, but it seems non-ideal to install a 3rd party package when Django already has the functionality built-in.

Answer (score 19):

Indeed it is possible to use the select2 from the admin.
You simply need to use the `AutocompleteSelect` widget. The AutocompleteSelect widget expects an relation and an admin site.

If you have model `A` that has a ForeignKey field pointing to model `B` for which you want to use the AutocompleteSelect, you simply can use (as suggested by [cuto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9503616/cuto))

```py
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AutocompleteSelect
from myapp.model import ModelA, ModelB
from django.contrib import admin


class MyForm(form.Form):
    model_b = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ModelB.objects.all(),
        widget=AutocompleteSelect(ModelA._meta.get_field('model_b').remote_field, admin.site)
    )
```

As I did not have a relation I used a `FakeRelation` class, as only the model property is used by the `get_url(self)` function.
The usage of the AutocompleteSelect widget is bound to the same condition as the the usage of the autocomplete_fields widget.

```py
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AutocompleteSelect
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from myapp.models import Countries
    
class FakeRelation:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
    
    
class CustomAutocompleteSelect(AutocompleteSelect):
    def __init__(self, model, admin_site, attrs=None, choices=(), using=None):
        rel = FakeRelation(model)
        super().__init__(rel, admin_site, attrs=attrs, choices=choices, using=using)

class PreventionPlanForm(form.Form):
    date_from = forms.DateField(label="From")
    date_to = forms.DateField(label="To")
    pe1_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=countries.objects.all(),
        widget=CustomAutocompleteSelect(Countries, admin.AdminSite)
    )
```

As [jenniwren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1302095/jenniwren) pointed out: Make sure to load the correct Javascripts/CSS files in your template (path could be subject to change in different django versions):

- admin/css/vendor/select2/select2.css
- admin/js/vendor/select2/select2.full.js
- admin/css/autocomplete.css
- admin/js/autocomplete.js

Or simple add `{{ form.media }}` to your template as pointed out by [software engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10201634/software-engineer).

Comment: Instead of creating a FakeRelation you may also use the actual relation from your ForeignKey field: `<model>._meta.get_field('<foreign key>').remote_field`.

Comment: That is a good and nice solution and probably helpful to some. In my case I only didn't have a Model that had a foreign key field to the model I wanted the autoselect widget for. 
I simply wanted to select and process it. Therefore I could not use your suggested solution.
Still it a good idea, I will edit the answer.

Comment: This (the first code) worked for me, but I had to change admin.AdminSite to admin.site

Comment: Which django version are you using? The fake relation solution with admin.AdminSite worked for me for Django 2.2.

Comment: Thanks for this solution!  This just took me a bit to figure out, even though it seems obvious now: Make sure you add the appropriate css/js files to your templates for non-admin pages. For Django 2.2 this includes `admin/css/vendor/select2/select2.css`, `admin/js/vendor/select2/select2.full.js`, `admin/css/autocomplete.css`, `admin/js/autocomplete.js`.

Comment: Instead of adding the static files yourself just add `{{form.media}}` in html template it will automatically import the required files.

Answer (score 7):

The FakeRelation solution proposed before does not work anymore with Django 2.2 which requires a field instance for the AutocompleteSelect constructor.
I had a suitable field in my project, so I could use it, but had to pass a field instance instead of a relation. Here is the code for a custom AutocompleteSelect  which also add the option to pass a specific placeholder to Select2:

```
class CustomAutocompleteSelect(AutocompleteSelect):
    def __init__(self, field, prompt="", admin_site=None, attrs=None, choices=(), using=None):
        self.prompt = prompt
        super().__init__(field, admin_site, attrs=attrs, choices=choices, using=using)

    def build_attrs(self, base_attrs, extra_attrs=None):
        attrs = super().build_attrs(base_attrs, extra_attrs=extra_attrs)
        attrs.update({
            'data-ajax--delay': 250,
            'data-placeholder': self.prompt,
            'style': 'width: 30em;'
        })
        return attrs


class AddLittermateForm(forms.Form):
    new_littermate = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Dog.objects.all(),
        widget=CustomAutocompleteSelect(LitterDog._meta.get_field(
            'dog'), "Search for a littermate here", admin.site)
    )
```

If one did not have a model with a suitable relation, they would have to declare one that is not managed:

```
...
class Meta:
    managed = False
```

Comment: This solution worked for me in Django 4.1
You probably want to add the addition to the template code from @skratt's answer:
`{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}`

Comment: I tried this solution but got the following error 

```File "/home/huzaifa/axya/backend_api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py", line 427, in optgroups
    selected_choices = {
  File "/home/huzaifa/axya/backend_api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py", line 429, in <setcomp>
    if str(v) not in self.choices.field.empty_values
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'field'```

Seems like I need to pass correct `choices` to the widget but I am stumped

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours trying to understand why my code would not work, until I stumble on @jenniwren comment about reference to css/js files. Here is a complete working solution.

To use the  AutocompleteSelect widget in any custom form for signed-in users having both 'staff' and 'view' access to the given model, you could declare the following:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AutocompleteSelect
from django.contrib import admin

class UserAutocompleteSelect(AutocompleteSelect):
    def get_url(self):
        model = CustomUser
        return reverse(self.url_name % (self.admin_site.name, model._meta.app_label, model._meta.model_name))

class UserChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, queryset=None, widget=None, **kwargs):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
        if widget is None:
            widget = UserAutocompleteSelect(None, admin.site)  # pass `None` for `rel`
        super().__init__(queryset, widget=widget, **kwargs)

class UserAutocompleteSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    for changing user on Play objects
    using amdin module autocomplete
    """
    user = UserChoiceField(
        # queryset=CustomUser.objects.all(),
        help_text=_('Select the user to replace the current one')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Play
        fields = ('user', )
```

You can use the same, replacing `CustomUser` and `Play` by your own models

And if this is not working out-of-the-box with the html template you're using, that means that you need to include the required css/js files to your template. Here is a simple way to do it :

Providing that the form is declared as such in the view:

```
form = UserAutocompleteSelectForm()
...
context = {
            'form': form, 
            ...
            }
return render(request, 'users/change_user.html', context)
```

you should add the following lines to the html template to include the required css/js files:

```
{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'admin/css/vendor/select2/select2.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'admin/css/autocomplete.css' %}"/>
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/select2/select2.full.js' %}" async></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/autocomplete.js' %}" async></script>
```

When you have one form

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    prefix = 'examplePrefix'
```

Manually use select2, you can use Ajax a data source

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_{{custom_form.prefix}}-device_types').select2();
});
</script>
```

In this way if you have multiple form in same view you can use prefixed field name and select2 with or without datasource.

**Hence no need to include 3rd party pip or CDN of any kind**