# ForeignKey form search via Text as opposed to Drop-Down - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, foreign-keys

I am working on a flight booking website on Django. In my `models.py`, I have two models; one called **Airport** and one called **Flight**. The **Flight** class has two variable's called '*Departure*' and '*Destination*' which inherit from from the **Airport** class via a foreign key.

Ultimately, I want the user to be able to select a departing airport and a destination airport. Now,I am limited to the drop-down option when trying to query airports.

Can someone please explain a way to go about editing my form to where a user can type in an airport name and the stored values will appear based on the users search. (ex: A user enters "los " and "Los Angeles" appears and can be selected.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Airport(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.city} ({self.code})"

class Flight(models.Model):
    origin = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="origin")
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="destination")
    length = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} - {self.origin} to {self.destination}"
```

Below, in my forms.py file; I have added a widget dict which has allowed me to now enter in a value to the form as opposed to having a drop down menu. However, it does not suggest results based on the search nor does it prompt any of the stored airports.

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Airport, Flight
from django.forms import CharField


class citySearch(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Flight
        fields = ['origin', 'destination']
        widgets = {
            "origin": forms.TextInput,
            "destination": forms.TextInput
        }
```

Below, in my views.py; I know there's some odd code in here but I'm leaving it for the sake of there being no "bugs".

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Airport, Flight
from .forms import citySearch

def index(request):
    airports = Airport.objects.all()
    context ={
        "airports": airports,
    }
    return render(request, "base/index.html" , context)


def book(request):
    form = citySearch()
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = citySearch(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "base/book.html" , context)
```

Lastly is my HTML file. Just adding it in case!

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Flights </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='POST' action="{% url 'book' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form }}</p>

            <input type="submit" value ='Search'/>
        </form>
        <h3> Finding flights</h3>
        <h1> from {{ departure }} to {{destination}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this was clear. I did not think this would be so difficult.

I feel like I have tried everything but then again everything I have looked at has been different and hard to apply to my exact case.

Comment: you can take a look at this answer, because django admin already had auto complete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57143113/how-to-use-the-admin-autocomplete-field-in-a-custom-form

Comment: @LinhNguyen Not sure if you've attempted this but django is having a hard time recognizing the installed library (atleast in my case). Surely there is a method that does not require third party extensions?

Comment: the first answer of the post doesn't use third party at all, it used the built in django admin select2 autocomplete input field